# How do I make a trimmed video show the missing frames from a Zoom recording using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, editing

I have a Zoom video that I "cut" into two videos:

```
ffmpeg -i 0131.mp4 -ss 55 -t 38:52 -codec copy 0131-1.mp4
ffmpeg -i 0131.mp4 -ss 40:00 -t 1:52 -codec copy 0131-2.mp4
```

I then merged into one using [concat demuxer][1] in ffmpeg.

The merged video plays, but the first 15 seconds of the merged video is blank (audio plays okay). What do I need to do so that first 15 seconds of the merged video also displays? Is this due to a "keyframe" not appearing for 15 seconds after my cut point?

> ```
> Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 32000 Hz, mono, fltp, 126 kb/s (default)
> Metadata:
>   creation_time   : 2021-01-31T21:53:20.000000Z
>   handler_name    : AAC audio
> Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 741 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 30k tbn, 60k tbc (default)
> Metadata:
>   creation_time   : 2021-01-31T21:53:20.000000Z
>   handler_name    : H.264/AVC video
>   encoder         : AVC Coding
> Stream #0:2(und): Data: bin_data (text / 0x74786574), 0 kb/s
> Metadata:
>   creation_time   : 2021-01-31T21:53:20.000000Z
>   handler_name    : Text
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Every time I concat, I quickly run it thru this awesome little freeware from Mean beforehand, [avidemux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/), (MP4 Muxer->Move index to the beginning of the file->Save) and it fixes the *majority* of any concat issues I've run into. Not sure if it will fix *your* issue, but it can't hurt and somewhere down the line avidemux *will* come in handy and fix a concat issue if you're having one. Shoutout to Mean for such a helpful piece of freeware!

Comment: wonder if this is the same in ffmpeg: ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -codec copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4 (stackoverflow.com/questions/7614635/…) I tried this in ffmpeg and no difference in results. I'll try avidemux and see if its any different.